# How do I change the font size in xgterm?

Tags: font-size

I can't handle these tiny letters any longer. How can I access the preferences in xgterm? I use xgterm for iraf so maybe there is a way to change prefrences from there.

edit: open this question

Comment: I feel like setting a font size in a terminal used for programming is directly on target with the directive mentioned in this hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XGterm uses the same font resources and options as the XTerm.  Fonts can be selected using the mouse menus but you need to define font1 thru font6 resources first, or else start with a defined font name such as

```
  % xgterm -fn 6x13
```